# Why isn't the file picker a derivative of the file browser

Tags: nautilus, gtk, nemo

So I went from Nautilus to Nemo file browser, but was surprised to see that the file picker (inside an app, when I choose "open a file". For example, ctrl+o on gedit) was exactly the same.

From [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/548802/735978) I learned that the file picker of inside an app (GTK+) is not the file browser. Apparently, it a also a [quite sensitive subject](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/71fcl9/desktop_lets_talk_about_the_gtk_file_picker/), and the only alternative to GTK+ is KGTK (thanks [here](https://superuser.com/a/1004269/1008757))

Why is it so complicated to have changes to the file picker, at the point that there is only one alternative to the default? In the linux world, I'm more used to too much alternatives than too few.

For what I'm able to see, the file picker share a lot with the file browser. In fact, I would have thought that the file picker would be the browser, where instead of executing an app when choosing a file, you would close the browser and return a string/filepath to the app. What is the fundamental difference that prevent transforming a browser onto a picker?

(sorry for approximate use of the terms, I'm not even sure picker/GTK and browser/Nemo are the right names)

Comment: See vanadium's answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1215893/248158) for some more information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make all applications use Nemo's file selection dialog instead of Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455747/how-can-i-make-all-applications-use-nemos-file-selection-dialog-instead-of-naut)

Comment: Not really... The question is why GTK has absolutely nothing to do with my default file browser (eg, Nemo, nautilus, dolphin...). I understood it is not the case, but it looks like very weird design to me